# How can I draw the following diagram from field theory?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, diagrams

How can I draw the following diagram using TikZ/PGF?

[image]

I have been able to draw up to the following diagram:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
  \node (Q) {$\mathbb{Q}$};
  \node (E) [above of=Q, left of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$};
  \node (E1) [above of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$};
  \node (F) [above of=Q, right of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$};
  \node (K) [above of=Q, node distance = 4cm] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$};
  \draw[-] (Q) to node {$2$} (E);
  \draw[-] (Q) to node [swap] {$2$} (F);
  \draw[-] (E) to node {$2$} (K);
  \draw[-] (F) to node [swap] {$2$} (K);
  \draw[-] (Q) to node [swap] {$2$} (E1);
  \draw[-] (E1) to node [swap] {$2$} (K);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

How can I extend this code to the above one?

Comment: Please provide a compilable minimal working example and not only a snippet of the code you use.

Comment: It will probably be better to see it as a 4 by 4 matrix. I'd also use `tikz-cd` as it is made for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @daleif, thanks for the idea. But my old latex editor does not accept `tikz-cd`

Comment: The editor has nothing to do with the packages. If you have `tikz-cd` installed you can use it no matter which editor. And if doing diagrams like this you should use it.

Comment: @daleif, yes you are right that `tikz-cd` is very helpful for mathematical diagram. I tried in the past but failed to install it. Can you give some precise idea how to add `tikz-cd` with my existing latex editor ?

Comment: You never install using your editor. Which latex installation are you using? It is listed among the first few lines in the log file.

Comment: @daleif,  I am using `MikTex+TexStudio`

Comment: Then miktex should just auto install `tikz-cd` if it is missing. And a proper updated TeXStudio should have syntax highlighting for it.

Comment: @daleif, ok. How to update `miktex` ?

Comment: the miktex console, it should already be installed on your system. If not, you haven't updated miktex for several years.

Comment: @daleif, I am trying to update MikTex. I downloaded the Tikz-CD package from  CTAN. I saved it in a folder giving a name. When I directing that file. It says `it does not seem a local package repository`. So what is a local package repository ? I think right here I am misunderstanding

Comment: You should not need to download anything manually. The miktex package manager can handle all of this for you. That is what it is there for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the code you already have, you could simply do something like this (but since the code you provided does not exactly result in the image you posted, I don't know what you really want to achieve):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node (Q) {$\mathbb{Q}$};
    \node (E) [above of=Q, left of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$};
    \node (E1) [above of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$};
    \node (F) [above of=Q, right of=Q] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$};
    \node (K) [above of=Q, node distance = 4cm] {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$};

    \node (G) [right of=F] {\color{blue}$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\gamma})$};

    \draw[-] (Q) to node {$2$} (E);
    \draw[-] (Q) to node {$2$} (F);
    \draw[-] (E) to node {$2$} (K);
    \draw[-] (F) to node {$2$} (K);
    \draw[-] (Q) to node {$2$} (E1);
    \draw[-] (E1) to node {$2$} (K);

    \draw[-] (Q) to node [swap] {$3$} (G);
    \draw[-] (G) to node [swap] {$2$} (K);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

In case you need the vertical offset of the nodes as well, you could achieve this by using a matrix, or (as noted in the comments) using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=1em] {
      & \color{blue}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[3]{2}) & & \\
      & \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) & \mathbb{Q}(\zeta\sqrt[3]{2}) & \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2}) \\
      \color{blue}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta) & & & \\
      & \color{blue}\mathbb{Q} & & \\
    };

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
        \draw (m-1-2) to node[left] {3} (m-3-1)
                      to node[below left] {2} (m-4-2);
        \draw (m-1-2) to node[right] {2} (m-2-2)
                      to node[right] {3} (m-4-2);
        \draw (m-1-2) to node[below left] {2} (m-2-3)
                      to node[right] {3} (m-4-2);
        \draw (m-1-2) to node[above right] {2} (m-2-4)
                      to node[below right] {3} (m-4-2);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also get the OP's image, but it differs a lot from the result they would like to have (not only regarding the offset). Therefore, it was not clear to me, whether they also wanted this offset or not. I just made a  rough guess that they wanted to include another node at the right (or left) oft the diagram.

Comment: I see. Well, in this case, daleifs comment about doing all this with a `tikz-cd` matrix is probably better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your both codes. I really liked the first one that extend my original code

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extending your code, I use plain TikZ. We even can write the one-liner code for the figure ^^

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) node (C) {$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$}
(2,0) node (R1) {$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta\sqrt[3]{2})$}
(4,0) node (R2) {$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2})$}
(0,1.5) node[blue] (A) {$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\sqrt[3]{2})$}
(0,-2) node[blue] (B) {$\mathbb{Q}$}
(-2,-1)  node[blue] (L) {$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$}
;
\draw[nodes={scale=.8}] (A)
to node[above]{$2$} (R2)
to node[below]{$3$} (B)
to node[below]{$2$} (L)
to node[left]{$3$} (A)
to node[below]{$2$} (R1)
to node[above]{$3$} (B)
to node[right]{$3$} (C)
to node[right]{$2$} (A)
;       
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. It worked nicely

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is one made using `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % incase " is active
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  &
  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})
  \arrow[ddl,-,"3"']
  \arrow[d,-,"2"]
  \arrow[dr,-,"2"']
  \arrow[drr,-,"2"]
  &
  &
  \\
  &
  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})
  \arrow[dd,-,"3"]
  &
  \mathbb{Q}(\zeta,\sqrt[3]{2})
  \arrow[ddl,-,"3"']
  &
  \mathbb{Q}(\zeta^2\sqrt[3]{2})
  \arrow[ddll,-,"3"]
  \\
  \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)
  \arrow[dr,-,"2"']
  &
  &
  &
  \\
  &
  \mathbb{Q}
  &
  &
  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it